# Firefox add-on get the DOM window which made an HTTP request

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm capturing the HTTP requests in a Firefox Add-on SDK extension. I need to get the DOM window associated with the request. However, I'm getting an `NS_NOINTERFACE` error.

Here is my code:

```
  var httpRequestObserver = {
    observe: function (subject, topic, data) {
      var httpRequest = subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
      var requestUrl = subject.URI.host;
      var domWin;
      var assWindow;
      console.log('URL: ', requestUrl);
      try {
        domWin = httpRequest.notificationCallbacks.getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
        assWindow = httpChannel.notificationCallbacks.getInterface(Ci.nsILoadContext)
                               .associatedWindow;
        console.log(domWin);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
      // console.log('TAB: ', tabsLib.getTabForWindow(domWin.top));

      var hostName = wn.domWindow.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow.location.host;
      console.log('HOST: ', hostName);
    },

    get observerService() {
      return Cc['@mozilla.org/observer-service;1'].getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);
    },

    register: function () {
      this.observerService.addObserver(this, 'http-on-modify-request', false);
    },

    unregister: function () {
      this.observerService.removeObserver(this, 'http-on-modify-request');
    }
  };

  httpRequestObserver.register();
```

I've tried both `nsIDOMWindow` and `nsILoadContext`, but `NS_NOINTERFACE` error always appears on an attempt to get the `window` object.

Comment: *Please*, [edit] the question to put console message information **in the question as text, contained in a `code block`**. If the error generates something that text can not convey, then an image of the error may be useful. However, in most cases, having an image of console messages is *significantly* less helpful than having them as text. When in text format, they can be copied, pasted, and searched. As text, they are **much** more useful both for answering the question and for people trying to find the answer to their similar problem in the future.

Comment: I have down-voted and voted to close due to not having the error information contained in the question as text. If you put the error messages into the question as text, I will remove my  down-vote and retract my close vote. In that case, I may up-vote. Please leave a comment with `@Makyen` so that I am notified of the change.

Comment: @Makyen thanks for help, updated.

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear. I did not mean just remove the image of the console messages. Please put the console messages in the question as text.  Console messages as text >> image of console error messages >>>>>> nothing (or little/incomplete information). If the image of the console errors has information you are not putting in the question as text, please leave the image of the console in the question.

Comment: @Makyen that console message is not important. It's a common one for firefox sdk and its name tells everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally managed to get the data I need via

```
httpRequest.notificationCallbacks.getInterface(Ci.nsILoadContext).topFrameElement
```

For example, to get url of the document which started the request, I used

```
httpRequest.notificationCallbacks.getInterface(Ci.nsILoadContext).topFrameElement._documentURI.href
```

Comment: Awesome job! Here is some documentation that might help out - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Getting_the_browser_that_fires_the_http-on-modify-request_notification_(example_code_updated_for_loadContext)

Comment: Do note though that this is not very e10s friendly. As you are working in process manager. It is much preferable to use nsIWebProgressListener from the framescript of each tab - https://github.com/Noitidart/Full-Stop/blob/master/resources/scripts/framescript.js

Comment: the URI can be obtained without using frame scripts. but touching the dom window will need them under e10s.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already found how to get the `<browser>` from the request you can do the following to get back to SDK APIs:

```
let browser = ....topFrameElement
let xulTab = browser.ownerDocument.defaultView.gBrowser.getTabForBrowser(browser)
let sdkTab = modelFor(xulTab)
```

[`modelFor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#Converting_to_XUL_tabs) is documented in the tabs module.